# Programatically downloaded file can not be opened in Android. It can be opened after I restart Android device. What may be the problem?

Tags: java, android, download

In an Android aplication, developed in Java, I download an apk from a web service. After downloading file to the mobile device (tablet) I can not open the file by clicking on it. I get "error" message when I try to open the downloaded file.
But If I copy the file using Android system copy function I can open the copied version.
If I restart the Android device the downloaded file can be opened.

What can be the problem in downloading  file?

This is the class that downloads file.
public class NewAppDownloader extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

```
Context context;
public NewAppDownloader(Context aContext) {
    this.context=aContext;
}

protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String downloadedAppFilePath= params[1];

    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;

    try {

        URL url = new URL(params[0]);
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/apk");
        connection.connect();
        int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();

        if (responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            // create directory
            File dir = new File(downloadedAppFilePath);
            dir.mkdirs();

            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(downloadedAppFilePath + "/my.apk");

            byte[] b = new byte[1024];

            int len = 0;
            while ((len = inputStream.read(b, 0, b.length)) != -1) {
                fileOutputStream.write(b, 0, len);
            }

            fileOutputStream.flush();
            fileOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fileOutputStream != null) {
                fileOutputStream.close();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    return "Download completed.";

}
protected void onPostExecute (String s){

    context=null;
}
```

}

This is the calling code in an onclick event

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    (new NewAppDownloader(getContext())).execute(appDownloadConnection,downloadedAppFilePath);


    }
```

Thanks in advance for all help and answers.

Comment: `downloadedAppFilePath` You forgot to initialize that variable. Nor did you tell us full path.

Comment: `I can not open the file by clicking on it. I get "error" message when I try to open the downloaded file` It is pretty unclear what you do or use when you see that file or try to use or open it.

Comment: `But If I copy the file using Android system copy function I can open the copied version.` Pretty unclear too. No idea what you do. And an Android system copy function? What is that?

Comment: `int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode()` That statement is much too early. You should first upload the file.

Comment: `return "Download completed.` You always return that. Also if there was a catch or a wrong return code. And where are you checking that message? I see nothing in onPostExecute().

Comment: My aim is to serve latest version of a application (apk) from aweb service. Download that application from a mobile application. And after donloaded automatically install the file by user interaction.     downloadedAppFilePath is a path of the web service for downloading file. I Initialize it. I download the apk file. After downloading it I want to install it by clicking. But it gives "error occured" message. When I copy the downloaded file I can open and install the apk. Or If I restart the device I can open the file and install the apk.

Comment: You did not give any of the information i asked for.

Comment: `downloadedAppFilePath is a path of the web service for downloading file.` ??? Dont think so. It looks more like a file system path to store the file.

Comment: I rewrite the original code for sending to public. I do not return "Download completed." from the function. I think the web service path is also unimportant for the problem. I tried whether it is working from other aplications and web browser. And web service is working. Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by design. Refer to the developer page on [alternative distribution](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/alternative-distribution), specifically the section on distributing through a website. Copied here for reference:

> If you don't want to release your apps on a marketplace such as Google Play, you can make them available for download on your website or server, including on a private or enterprise server. To do this, first prepare your apps for release in the normal way, then host the release-ready APK files on your website and provide users with a download link. To install an app distributed in this way, users must [opt-in for installing unknown apps](https://developer.android.com/distribute/marketing-tools/alternative-distribution#unknown-sources).

If your device already has that security restriction disabled, it might be that whatever app you are using to open the downloaded APK does not recognize it as that format. What app are you using to open it and what is the error message displayed? The reason it opens upon restart is likely due to the OS scanning and identifying it as an APK, such that whatever app you use to open it installs it successfully. Copying the downloaded file could also trigger the same process.

Also, [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask) has been deprecated. Consider using an [Executor](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/Executor) or some other modern concurrency pattern instead. Check out [Processes and Threads](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads) for alternatives or switch to Kotlin for even easier concurrency with [Coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines) :)

Comment: Thanks for your response and advices. 

In my device security restriction of "not enabling installation unknown applications"  has already been disabled.   

I changed the concurrency pattern and used Executor. After using Executor I can open and run the downloaded application file without copying it or restarting the device. I think the AsyncTask does not kill the thread and may hold a file handle.

Comment: Very nice! Yes, that is one of the main reasons AsyncTask has been deprecated -- potential resource leaks.